# COUNT function with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, count

I have the following table:

```
A  FromA  User
1  NULL   Bob
2  1      Bob
3  1      Chris
4  2      Chris
```

User is the name of the person who created item A. FromA is the source that the User grabbed it from.

I want to figure out is Chris' most frequency source.

My query

```
SELECT count(T1.A GROUP BY T1.User), T1.User
FROM Table T0 
INNER JOIN Table T1 ON T0.FromA=T1.A
WHERE T0.User='Chris'
```

It should return `Bob=2`. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t2.user, count(*) Total from t t1
join t t2 on t1.fromA = t2.a
where t1.user = 'Chris'
group by t2.user
order by Total desc
limit 1
```

The `limit 1` will give you just the most frequently used source.

**Edit:**

> inner join will fail to fetch record=>1 | NULL | Bob as 'fromA' column has null value. so, switch to left join – Angelin Nadar

Nope. Here is a [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b7e/1)

Comment: inner join will fail to fetch record=>1 | NULL | Bob as 'fromA' column has null value. so, switch to left join

Comment: @AngelinNadar I don't need to use a left join and using it is less efficient. The query is tested. Please, reanalyze the data. Think what would a query with given data return if using a left join and querying for user Bob!

Answer (score 1):

You just have your group by in the wrong place. This should work

```
SELECT count(T1.A ), T1.User
FROM Table T0 
INNER JOIN Table T1 ON T0.FromA=T1.A
WHERE T0.User='Chris'
GROUP BY T1.User
```

Comment: Your are missing Chris' most frequency source

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, I have changed table aliases:

```
SELECT count(*), t_User.User
FROM 
  Table t_FromA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  Table t_User 
   ON t_User.FromA=t_FromA.A
WHERE t_FromA.User='Chris'
```